# Присоединение конвертора XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Коллеги, в процессе работы я решил собрать все конвертеры в одном месте. Завел папку `Converters` и начал их складывать туда.

Структура тестового проекта выглядит следующим образом:
[image]

Далее я подключаю конвертер на странице LoginPage:

```
<Page
    x:Class="WpfApplication.LoginPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Model.Converters"
    xmlns:local="using:WpfApplication"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <converters:BoolInvert x:Key="BoolInvert"/>
    </Page.Resources>
</Page>
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Имя "BoolInvert" не существует в пространстве имен
>   "clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Model.Converters".

Хотя когда пишу `<converters:`, всплывающая подсказка показывает `BoolInvert`.

Что я делаю не правильно?

---

**UPD**
Код файла `BoolInvert.cs`

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace WpfApplication.Model.Converters
{
    public class BoolInvert : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string lang)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string lang)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно класс в  файле `BoolInvert.cs` имеет другой namespace

Comment: @S.Kost Добавил код конвертера. Там верно все?

Comment: вроде правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После добавления в XAML нового пространства имен нужно сделать Build проекта. Часто помогает, для WPF проектов особенно. Смотрите комментарий ниже.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Я понял. У вас ошибка в XAML объявлении. В Win8.1 используется using:. а у вас как для WPF clr-namespace

Comment: Спасибо. Вы абсолютно правы. Я пробовал писать `using:`, но не делал ребилд проекта, поэтому ошибка оставалась. Если написать `using:` и сделать ребилд, то проблема решается